Home Network Questions: Router (Fritz Box) + AdGuard Home + Personal VPN (Mullvad) + VPN for my mobile phone/laptop when I'm outside
I have my home network setup as follows:

Router FRITZ!Box 5590 Fiber
AdGuard Home DNS server using a Raspberry Pi 5 and configured using:

Upstream DNS servers:

https://dns.cloudflare.com/dns-query
https://adblock.doh.mullvad.net/dns-query


And DNS Blocklist:

HaGeZi's Threat Intelligence Feeds
HaGeZi's Ultimate Blocklist
Steven Black's List
AdGuard DNS filter
Dan Pollock's List




I also have a VPN (WireGuard) configured in the router so I can connect while I'm outside.

On the other hand and where my question rely is, I paid for Mullvad VPN and I use it mostly while I'm outside home too, using my Mobile Network or other Wi-Fi.
Is it possible and/or interesting to have Mullvad configured in my router also? I tried many times to have both Mullvad VPN and my Home VPN but somehow both VPN configurations interfere from each other.
Is it secure and healthy enough to navigate only using my Home VPN or should I keep connecting using a third party VPN?
